# Actionbar button is not showing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

My toolbar button is not showing in fragments i tried with **setHasOptionsMenu(true);** . when i click on navigation drawer item it loads new fragment  for the each fragment i want to show different action bar button(notification or save). Following is my code,thanks in advance.

Following is my **Fragment** code: (It is same for all fragments in navigation drawer)

```
public class Company1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_company_profile,container, false);

    init(view);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddDialog();
        }
    });


    return view;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.company_profile, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.notification:
            break;

     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

}
```

This is **company_profile.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_notification"
        android:title="@string/mnuNotificationText"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
  </menu>
```

Comment: Is it not showing up in any fragment at all or only in some cases (not getting updated, etc.)?

Comment: not in all fragments with navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code snippet

```
public class Company1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  }

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_company_profile,container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    init(view);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddDialog();
        }
    });


    return view;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.company_profile, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.notification:
            break;

     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       //You can change menuitem property
       //menu.findItem(R.id.notification).setVisible(true);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
}
```